# How to deactivate an active tab for another because of a hashtag in the url?

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, hashtag

I have a tab that is already activated, but I want to deactivate that tab for another if a hashtag points to another tab.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="active">
        <a class="default-tab" href="#default-tab">About</a>
    </li>


    <li>
        <a class="brand-tab" href="#brand-tab">Brand</a>
    </li>
</ul>


<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="default-tab active" id="default-tab">
        <p>...</p>
    </div>

    <div class="brand-tab" id="boc-brand">
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (location.hash === "#brand", function() {
            $(".brand-tab").addClass('active', function() {
                $(".default-tab").removeClass('active');
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: Uh, a basic if statement doesn't take a callback. `if (boolean expression) { ...logic... }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got callbacks in there where they don't belong. This is the code you need:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (location.hash === "#brand") {
        $(".brand-tab").addClass('active');
        $(".default-tab").removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Edit:

If those are Bootstrap tabs as it looks like by that markup, you're better off using the built-in Bootstrap method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (location.hash === "#brand") {
        $('a[href="#brand-tab"]').tab('show');
    }
});
```